# Get current month in office scripts

Tags: excel, ms-office

I'm having some problems getting the current month in office scripts. I understand you can get the current date, would it be possible to extract the current month only?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, in what format do you want the date, e.g. month number/name?

Answer (score 0):

If this is actually Office Scripts and not VBA you can try this.

```
// get current month number, note this is zero-indexed i.e. 0 = January, 1 = February
const monthNum = new Date().getMonth()

// get full current month name for locale, to get abbreviated name replace 'long' with 'short'
const monthName  = new Date().toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
```